# Android drawing on layers

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, overlay, layer

Hi I'm making a drawing application, I'm loading a picture in a canvas, I then want to overlay stickers on it But I want to be able to remove any sticker at any time during the process. It's incredibly painful to restore the background image when I decide to remove the sticker. Is there a way to draw each sticker on different layer so I only have to clear the layer to era the sticker.
Am I clear?

Answer (score 1):

Not really, other than using 1 bitmap per sticker and forming the final screen by drawing all those bitmaps on top of each other.  But even if you could-  layers aren't magic.  When you cleared one, to get the final result you'd still have to composite them all again, which means just as much work for your program.

Comment: How do photo editing apps work exactly? Those phot apps where you can add stickers and resize them. Do they use one canvas and draw everything on it or do they use on canvas per stickers that act like layers?